Should decoupling be made before PC817 opto-coupler?
I am having trouble with "duplicated" signals when my microprocessor receives digital input. I think that the lack of proper decoupling could cause the issue, but I don't have the knowledge to confirm if this could be the issue.
For context, I have a board that needs to work in industrial environment receiving 24v input from a relay or from a PLC, but I consistently have the issue that, on the falling edge of the input waves, the signal "bounces" once more and the microprocessor receives 2 signals instead of 1. I've been handling the issue with software, but this does not seem like the smart solution.
Here's the design i am dealing with:

[EDIT]: After @Voltage Spike's response I got my hands on a o-scope and did some measuments. It is a really cheap one hahaha. But here is some readings for additional context. (CH1 is the signal that arrives at an ESP32 pin, CH2 is the input 24v signal that comes from a S7 500 plc)
The images are of the falling edge of the pulse. I choose not to include pictures of the rising edge because the "bouncing" only happens in the falling edge phase of the wave.


Sorry if the measurements don't bring much. It's my first time using a o-scope.
My hunch is that there should exist decoupling for the 24v input, before the PC817. But I don't know how to confirm this or argue that this could be a problem. [EDIT]: After the o-scope measurements I am thinking that the problem might be how slow the pulse transitions to logical low I will try to explore ways to deal with this.
Any insight or tips on what could be done or argued? Or this is not a likely source of problems?
EDIT: The TVS diode is incorrect. In the finished board P6KE36CA diodes are used. Sorry if this causes confusion.

P6KE6.8CA won't last very long at 24V... are you sure the schematic is correct?

@TimWilliams. You're right, I looked at the finished board that i got and the diodes have P6KE36CA inscribed on them.

That could be it, but you really need a way to detect a threshold. It's likely that you are getting some kind of ringing on the 24V line.
This will translate directly into the microprocessor because the voltage with an opto isnt on/off, if the signal get's to 12V and then goes up and then down, you'll see that in the 3.3V line. And if that happens near the Vh threshold of the microprocessor you'll see a double pulse.
I would suggest looking at the 24V line when it's transitioning with an o-scope and at the same time, look at the 3.3V line.
I would also suggest looking at a schmitt trigger between the opto and the microprocessor that has hysteresis to
You could potentially solve this with an RC lowpass filter also, but it depends on the nature of the noise, and usually microprocessors want a voltage low or voltage high signal so being in between is not good.

Thank you for the quick answer. I will try to do some measurements with an o-scope to find more information.

It depends if the problem is on the 24V side or on the MCU side.
Both can be problems.
The 24V could have some rippling that makes the LED emitter to pulse instead of just cleanly turning on or off, or it may drop very slowly so the LED fades away instead of turns off quickly and cleanly.
The same applies on the MCU side regardless of the LED side.
There is a 10k pull-down with 100nF capacitor. Even if the transistor turns off cleanly and instantly, the time constant of the RC filter is 1 millisecond where the voltage falls slowly.
MCU inputs do not work well with slow signals that linger between logic levels near the threshold for a long time. Any noise will make the signal to cross threshold multiple times, and it is especially bad if you use interrupts to detect edges of slow signals.
Either handle the signal cleanly on the 24V side or MCU side wherever the problem is found to be. Or handle the multiple edges with filtering and introducing dead time. Or do not use interrupts from the signal. You could check if there are captured edges and then determine the signal being stable if there is no captured signal edges.

Thank you for the insights. Yeah I've been using interrupts all over the place, and I am using a timer of around 20 ticks, that sets of with the interrupt, where the interrupt is turned off so no more signals are received. After the timer the interrupt works again. This solves the problem, but resources are valuable and these timers consume too much memory. But thank you again, i will look into what you mentioned.
